# How to implement a Common spectral pattern (CSP) in the real-time application?

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to implement "Common Spatial Pattern (CSP)" as a feature extraction method.
But most of the implementation of CSP that available is in binary or multiclass (input: minimum requirement two-class). So, If I want to use it in a real-time application, how can I implement this? (At that time, we will put a single observation for the testing purpose that contain a single class).
I will be grateful if anyone help to understand the logic of CSP in the real-time application.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, it is a good idea to measure the time of CSP using [mne.decoding.CSP](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.decoding.CSP.html). Finally, if you have any speed issue depending on your sampling rate and windowing strategy, you can do some common strategies to reach the real-time (considering the fact that c and c++ is the core language used in many online applications and linear algebra libraries):
1- Increasing the windowing size and decreasing  the overlap size. It might solve the issue of being online, along with the  [multi-threaded pipeline](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-multi-threaded-pipeline-in-c-with-std-async-78edc19e862d) technique!
2- Firstly, implement your own code for [CSP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_spatial_pattern) (or find an open-source code). Secondly, implement a [multi-threaded pipeline](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-multi-threaded-pipeline-in-c-with-std-async-78edc19e862d), where each thread do one step of CSP algorithm. Having said that, there would be an slight delay when a pipeline is started, though it can be continued at live rate if enough resources is available. I would like to mention that the main part of **CSP** algorithm  is **Eigen Decomposition**, for which there are excellent implementations either on **CPU**, based on [**OpenCV**](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf51987e03cac8d171fbd2b327cf966f6)  and [**Eigen**](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html), or **GPU** based on [**Cuda CuSolver**](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html).